# Reference Color

Tags: cross-referencing

```
\documentclass[preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=black, linkcolor=black, urlcolor=black]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

 ... \cite{ML1986} .....

... see \hyperlink{app}{\textcolor{black}{appendix}} ....

\appendix
\hypertarget{app}{\section*{Appendix.}}

section*{Mass matrix}
     ....

\section*{Gyroscopic matrix}
     ...

 \end{document}
```

I get the following

[image]

How can I put the reference [17] in black not in blue?

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing an official paper for this journal, you should not change their defaults. However, `elsarticle` checks, if `hyperref` is loaded. If it finds this package, it does its own color definitions `\AtBeginDocument`. If you just do your own `\hypersetup` the very moment after that, you will have forced `elsarticle` to use your style.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{ML1986,
        author = {Mest Lest},
        year = {1986},
        title = {Test},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\hypersetup{%
    ,urlcolor=black
    ,citecolor=black
    ,linkcolor=black
    }
\cite{ML1986}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

---

The normal procedure, however, would be to do `\usepackage[colorlinks=false, hidelinks]{hyperref}`. But I guess, you want to have some colors somewhere.

Comment: I think that `colorlinks=false` suffices.

Comment: @egreg A bit. But this would result in green boxes... I suggested that S_25 does not want that. I do not know, what else is desired by the OP. @S_25, you can load `\usepackage[colorlinks=false, hidelinks]{hyperref}` instead. But I guess, you have tried that already.

Comment: I see no green box at all.

Comment: @egreg Are you using `elsarticle`? With my MWE I get green boxes for `\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}` and `\begin{document}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=false}`

Comment: It may depend on the PDF viewer

Answer (score 0):

First attempt:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{ML1986,
        author = {Mest Lest},
        year = {1986},
        title = {Test},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[
  %colorlinks=true,
]{hyperref}

\AtBeginDocument{% optionally set colors to your liking
  \hypersetup{
    urlcolor=red,
    citecolor=green,
    linkcolor=blue,
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com}

\cite{ML1986}

\hyperlink{app}{appendix}

\appendix
\hypertarget{app}{\section*{Appendix.}}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

The output is without colors:

[image]

If I uncomment the `colorlinks=true` line, the result is colored:

[image]

Without the `\hypersetup` instruction, you get the colors predefined by `elsarticle` (provided you have `colorlinks=true`).